# Automating SSh communication without Password Prompt

Tags: bash, shell, centos, ssh

I want to communicate host1 to host2 using ssh,

Lets think i have username/pwd of host2 , i want to connect to host2 using ssh via shell script, (which takes username and pwd as parameters)

can someone help me to write the shell script for the same ?

Comment: I had tried below 1) tried to send password using read command , Note : i dont want to disable password checking using some strict hostcheckong false 2) even i dont want to use public/private keys mechanism

Comment: I am very new to Linux env

Comment: _i dont want to use public/private keys mechanism_ - Then you don't want to use the right solution to your problem. Good luck keeping your account from getting pwned. _shrug_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think writing down a password is a good idea. Have a look at `ssh` keys. You just have to create a pair of public and private keys in `host1` and copy the public key inside `host2`. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) is a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: I cant see any link !!!

Comment: Is there anyway, where i can remove the known host ..please guide me, if there is such possibilty

Comment: @sharath just click on "Here"

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works, you need to install `expect` for making it work
    #!/bin/bash

```
HOSTS="VM2 VM3 VM4 VM1"

read -p "Password: " PASSWORD

for HOST in $HOSTS
do
expect -c "
your command 
    expect {
    "*password:*" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
    }
    exit
    "
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ssh-agent` and `sshpass`.

If they do not solve your problem, please explain why they do not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make persistent ssh communications, you can use a utility like autossh.

Comment: This is more a vague hint than an answer. Please add some details such as a specific command.